# Query a database in google sheets and only select when numbers pass a minimum requested

Tags: database, windows

So I have over 250 countries with 80 products.. Currently my system works if the country says yes it shows the rate for the product at that country.
I want to change the formula so I can put a minimum rate for each product for each country, so the query checks if it passes the minrate for the country and then displays

This is what I was initially `using: =arrayformula( if( transpose(Configuration!B16:B262) = "yes", Full!H1:IT200, iferror(1/0) ) )`

I don't know how to do this though in a single formula though and think I would rather do it in a single formula..because I have over 50 partner sheets I need to change the formula...
thought something like this but I have no idea.... `=query( Full!H1:IT200, "select * where * >'"&transpose(Configuration!B16:B262)&"')")`

I tried this.. `=arrayformula( if( Full!H1:IT200 > (transpose(Configuration!B16:B262)), Full!H1:IT200, iferror(1/0) ) )`

I tried putting it in multiple columns with this: `=query( Full!H1:H200, "select * where H > '"&Configuration!$B$16&"' ",1 )` and no luck..

Here is my sample database: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/#folders/0B-q2iTkqKqbJbWIwbUFIMncxY3c
You can use the DB file